# FxOS Marketplace App Submission. Is it automatically available / downloadable to the public or not?

Tags: app-store, marketplace, firefox-os

Does an app automatically become available to the public after submission or not? I want to make it private first, then set it to public if I'm ready.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

When you submit your application to the marketplace, you can request to make the app available to the public only when you want, so once your application is approved, you will need to log in to the Firefox Marketplace and make it public manually. If you don't ask for this, the application will be available to the public a couple of minutes after the review team approved it.